# Importing css and js into Rails 4.2.4 app using @import or require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I need to import some files into application.css or application.js files.
For example, for css I use @import statements.
I have some stylesheets in a vendor/assets/stylesheets directory:

```html
vendor/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css
vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css
etc
```

So I use:

```html
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'simple-line-icons';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Here I was able to load the font-awesome file, but not bootstrap or simple-line-icons. I got this error:

```html
File to import not found or unreadable: file_name.css
```

Quite strange. Is the general idea of importing files from vendor directory correct? Or should I put those files in some other directory?

P.S: I know you might ask why I am importing bootstrap manually and not using a gem; the answer is that I bought some templates and I want to include all files from the templates to be consistent.

Comment: Your idea of importing files from `vendor/assets/stylesheets` is perfectly correct. Have you tried to use `@import 'bootstrap.min'`?

Comment: @AlexanderKomarov, thanks, it helped. Generally the problem was that font-awesome was loaded via gem dependency.

Comment: That makes sense, I was wondering why you could import `font-awesome` and not `bootstrap`. AFAIK I should convert my comment into an actual answer. Will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea of importing files from `vendor/assets/stylesheets` is absolutely correct. Files imported from somewhere else (not written by yourself) should go there.

However, you should do `@import bootstrap.min`, not `@import bootstrap`.

Also, it's probably better to put `*= require bootstrap.min` into your `application.css` as @Rendrum pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Assets owned by outside entities should be placed in the `vendor/assets` directory, so it could be managed by rails successfully.

In order to include them in your app you can load them automatically by using these expressions in your `application.css`

```
*= require font-awesome
*= require simple-line-icons
*= require bootstrap
```

I suggest you to read this in order to understand how rails works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Thanks [Alexander Komarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6185382/alexander-komarov) for the corrections :)

Comment: `app/assets` is for your own assets. For assets taken from somewhere else you should use `vendor/assets` directory instead.

Comment: It's not `app/vendor/assets` though, it's just `vendor/assets` :)